# Selenium Multiple Selectors can't locate elements

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am trying to interact with a button. Selenium/Nightwatch.js can not locate.

The button is not within a different iframe. 
I have tried multiple selectors, none of them working.
The elements are not hidden and can be clicked upon manually. 
Also I have tried adding waits, in-order to ensure it is not a timing issue.

I can verify the existence of the body, after-which no other elements are visible to selenium.

My Code:

```js
.pause(5000)
.useCss()
.verify.visible('.coral-MinimalButton.toggle-sidepanel.editor-GlobalBar-item.js-editor-SidePanel-toggle')
.verify.visible('html.wf-adobeclean-i4-active.wf-adobeclean-n3-active.wf-adobeclean-n4-active.wf-adobeclean-n7-active.wf-adobecleancondensed-n4-active.wf-adobecleancondensed-n7-active.wf-active body.coral--light div#Content.editor-panel.editor-panel-active div.editor-GlobalBar.js-editor-PanelHeader.editor-panel-header nav.coral-Panel-header.coral-GlobalBar-main.header-main div.editor-GlobalBar-leftContainer button.coral-MinimalButton.toggle-sidepanel.editor-GlobalBar-item.js-editor-SidePanel-toggle')
.click('.coral-MinimalButton.toggle-sidepanel.editor-GlobalBar-item.js-editor-SidePanel-toggle')
.click('html.wf-adobeclean-i4-active.wf-adobeclean-n3-active.wf-adobeclean-n4-active.wf-adobeclean-n7-active.wf-adobecleancondensed-n4-active.wf-adobecleancondensed-n7-active.wf-active body.coral--light div#Content.editor-panel.editor-panel-active div.editor-GlobalBar.js-editor-PanelHeader.editor-panel-header nav.coral-Panel-header.coral-GlobalBar-main.header-main div.editor-GlobalBar-leftContainer button.coral-MinimalButton.toggle-sidepanel.editor-GlobalBar-item.js-editor-SidePanel-toggle')
.useXpath()
.verify.visible('//html/body/div[4]/div[1]/nav/div[1]/button[1]')
.click('//html/body/div[4]/div[1]/nav/div[1]/button[1]')
// again pointing to the same element now using partial css
.useCss()
.verify.visible('button[title="Toggle Side Panel"]')
.click('button[title="Toggle Side Panel"]')
// Trying to verify the body is locatable  
.verify.visible('body[class="coral--light"]')
// This verifies I can locate the body  
.verify.visible('html.wf-adobeclean-i4-active.wf-adobeclean-n3-active.wf-adobeclean-n4-active.wf-adobeclean-n7-active.wf-adobecleancondensed-n4-active.wf-adobecleancondensed-n7-active.wf-active body.coral--light')
```

```html
<body class="coral--light">
    <div class="foundation-authoring-ui-mode hidden" data-classic-editor-                
        url="/cf#"></div>
    <div class="foundation-content-path hidden" data-foundation-content-   
        path="/content/citypages/en/test3.html"></div>
    <div id="SidePanel" class="sidepanel sidepanel-closed">
        <div class="sidepanel-header editor-GlobalBar">
            <nav class="toolbar" data-init="toolbar">
                <div class="left icongroup">
                    <span class="sidepanel-header-title sidepanel-header-title-assetfinder"    
     title="Search Assets" style="display: none;">Search Assets</span>
                    <span class="sidepanel-header-title sidepanel-header-title-components"     
     title="Components" style="display: inline;">Components</span>
                </div>
                <div class="right icongroup">
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="sidepanel-content sidepanel-content-with-header">
        <div class="sidepanel-resizer"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Content" class="editor-panel editor-panel-active">
        <div class="editor-GlobalBar js-editor-PanelHeader editor-panel-header">
            <nav class="coral-Panel-header coral-GlobalBar-main header-main">
                <div class="editor-GlobalBar-leftContainer">
                    <button class="coral-MinimalButton toggle-sidepanel editor-GlobalBar-item js-   
      editor-SidePanel-toggle" data-align="left" data-iconsize="S" title="Toggle    
      Side Panel" autocomplete="off" type="button">
```

The last <kbd>button</kbd> is the one. What do I need to do to try to locate the element?

Comment: Could you also mention what you have tried from your side.

Comment: i've set the frame to null.

Comment: added waits. and tried multiple selectors

Comment: Why wouldn't The given xpaths/css from Firebug not work?

Comment: double negative *work

Answer (score 0):

You can try below xpath:-

```
//button[@title='Toggle Side Panel']
```

Comment: That did not work either. I don't believe it has anything to do with the specific selector choosen.

Comment: in your code you have written:-                                                                       .verify.visible('button[title="Toggle Side Panel"]')
.click('button[title="Toggle Side Panel"]')                   here xpath should start with double forward slash "//"

Answer (score 0):

This selector is way more verbose than needed, but I did it this way so you can see how it traverses the page to get there.  It works when I run it on the above code.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body.coral--light div#Content button[type=button]")
```

If that doesn't work, there is something else about the page that is affecting the element visibility.  If the page is public send the URL and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't a issue with the selector

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for changing windows in javascript, I closed the first then switched to the second. Thanks to everyone for your time and consideration.

```
  .closeWindow()
  .pause(1000)
  .window_handles(function(result) {
      var newHandle = result.value[0];
      this.switchWindow(newHandle);
        })
```